# PyQT Multimedia Issue

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, qt5, qtmultimedia

So, I am having quite a time getting the video player in QT 5.5.1 created in QML to work with PyQt5 installed from Ubuntu. In fact, everything is installed from Ubuntu so I am fairly certain the Qt versions are correct. The QML will not load but get the error presented below.

How can I get the video player and the rest of the multimedia toolkit in QT5 to work in PyQt5?

I installed the following:

```
appmenu-qt5/xenial-updates,now 0.3.0+16.04.20170216-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libaccounts-qt5-1/xenial,now 1.14+16.04.20151106.1-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libdbusmenu-qt5/xenial,now 0.9.3+16.04.20160218-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libqt5clucene5/xenial,now 5.5.1-3build1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5concurrent5/xenial-updates,now 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5core5a/xenial-updates,now 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 amd64 [installed]
libqt5dbus5/xenial-updates,now 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 amd64 [installed]
libqt5designer5/xenial,now 5.5.1-3build1 amd64 [installed]
libqt5designercomponents5/xenial,now 5.5.1-3build1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5feedback5/xenial,now 5.0~git20130529-0ubuntu13 amd64 [installed]
libqt5glib-2.0-0/xenial,now 1.2.0-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5gstreamer-1.0-0/xenial,now 1.2.0-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5gstreamer-dev/xenial,now 1.2.0-3 amd64 [installed]
libqt5gstreamerquick-1.0-0/xenial,now 1.2.0-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5gstreamerui-1.0-0/xenial,now 1.2.0-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5gstreamerutils-1.0-0/xenial,now 1.2.0-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5gui5/xenial-updates,now 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 amd64 [installed]
libqt5help5/xenial,now 5.5.1-3build1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5multimedia5/xenial,now 5.5.1-4ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
libqt5multimedia5-plugins/xenial,now 5.5.1-4ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
libqt5multimediaquick-p5/xenial,now 5.5.1-4ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
libqt5multimediawidgets5/xenial,now 5.5.1-4ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5network5/xenial-updates,now 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 amd64 [installed]
libqt5opengl5/xenial-updates,now 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 amd64 [installed]
libqt5opengl5-dev/xenial-updates,now 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5organizer5/xenial,now 5.0~git20140515~29475884-0ubuntu20 amd64 [installed]
libqt5positioning5/xenial,now 5.5.1-3ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libqt5printsupport5/xenial-updates,now 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 amd64 [installed]
libqt5qml5/xenial,now 5.5.1-2ubuntu6 amd64 [installed]
libqt5quick5/xenial,now 5.5.1-2ubuntu6 amd64 [installed]
libqt5quickparticles5/xenial,now 5.5.1-2ubuntu6 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5quicktest5/xenial,now 5.5.1-2ubuntu6 amd64 [installed]
libqt5quickwidgets5/xenial,now 5.5.1-2ubuntu6 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5script5/xenial,now 5.5.1+dfsg-2build1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5sql5/xenial-updates,now 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 amd64 [installed]
libqt5sql5-sqlite/xenial-updates,now 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 amd64 [installed]
libqt5svg5/xenial,now 5.5.1-2build1 amd64 [installed]
libqt5test5/xenial-updates,now 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 amd64 [installed]
libqt5webkit5/xenial,now 5.5.1+dfsg-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libqt5widgets5/xenial-updates,now 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 amd64 [installed]
libqt5x11extras5/xenial,now 5.5.1-3build1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5xml5/xenial-updates,now 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 amd64 [installed]
libqt5xmlpatterns5/xenial,now 5.5.1-2build1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libsignon-qt5-1/xenial,now 8.58+16.04.20151106-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
python-pyqt5/xenial,now 5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python-pyqt5-dbg/xenial,now 5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python-pyqt5.qtmultimedia/xenial,now 5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]
python-pyqt5.qtmultimedia-dbg/xenial,now 5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]
python3-pyqt5/xenial,now 5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python3-pyqt5-dbg/xenial,now 5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia/xenial,now 5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]
python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia-dbg/xenial,now 5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]
python3-pyqt5.qtquick/xenial,now 5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]
python3-pyqt5.qtquick-dbg/xenial,now 5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]
python3-pyqt5.qtx11extras/xenial,now 5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]
python3-pyqt5.qtx11extras-dbg/xenial,now 5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]
qt5-default/xenial-updates,now 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 amd64 [installed]
qt5-qmake/xenial-updates,now 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
qtgstreamer-plugins-qt5/xenial,now 1.2.0-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Despite installing libqt5multimedia, libqtmultimediaquick and libqt multimedia declarative, and seeing the video player in QT creator, I cannot seem to get the video player to work.

I receive the following error when running my code:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
file:///home/me/PycharmProjects/EduTech/app/resources/qml/vplayer.qml:2 plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtMultimedia": Cannot load library /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtMultimedia/libdeclarative_multimedia.so: (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5MultimediaQuick_p.so.5: version `Qt_5_PRIVATE_API' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtMultimedia/libdeclarative_multimedia.so))
```

I run my qml as follows:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine.load(QUrl('../app/resources/qml/vplayer.qml'))

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Cannot load library /usr/**local**/lib/python3.5/... ?!

Comment: That seems to do it thanks. Totally didn't notice that for some reason.